# remote: true without repond_to format.js in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have sending button with remote: true attribute, and if my controller doesnt have respond_to format.js, data, sended by button with remote: true, is showing without refresing web page. This behaviour incorrect?

Comment: I believe with remote=true you won't refresh the web page... that's how it's suppose to work. But I don't understand the question very well, could you elaborate?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements

Comment: To expand on the comment from @SebastianPalma (just a wee bit): This behavior is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`remote: true` option is mostly used for ajax request. For example you can do something on back-end only or return some javascript code that will do something with your current html page. So yes, such behavior is a norm.

There is more information in [official rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).